# Issues using DataTestMethod and DataRow attributes in MS Test

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mstest

I have installed MS Test V2 in my VS 2015 instance using nuGet and I have successfully added `DataTestMethod` and `DataRow` attributes to my unit tests and they compile, but now when I build, the tests don't show up in Test Explorer.

Example:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("YAHOO", "GOOGLE")]
public void TestCheckSite(string site)
{
     ... do stuff here ...
}
```

What am I missing? Is there a Test Explorer upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Install MSTest Framework:    https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/
- If you are building for .NET Core, then install this adapter:    https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-test-mstest/
- However, if you are building for desktop .NET/UWP, install this adapter instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/
- Now write the tests and build your solution. The tests ought to show up in the Test Explorer.

Please let me know if you still do not see the tests showing up.

Comment: It's complaining that there's a processor architecture mismatch. My project is MSIL but the `dotnet-test-mstest` that I got from nuget is AMD64.

Comment: I've tried 1.0.1 and 1.1.1 and they both give me the processor architecture mismatch. I don't know why it would be getting an AMD specific version.

Comment: I misunderstood and was doing `dotnet-test-mstest`, not `MSTest.TestAdapter`. I also had to restart VS.NET after installing it. Works now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("YAHOO")]
[DataRow("GOOGLE")]
public void TestCheckSite(string site) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, once I got it showing up in Test Explorer, that was the first thing I fixed.